# how does elasticsearch decide how many shards can be restored in parallel

Tags: elasticsearch

I made a snapshot of an index with 24 shards. The index is of size 700g.
When restoring, it restores 4 shards in parallel.

My cluster is a new cluster with only one machine w/o replica nodes. 
The machine is AWS c3.8xlarge with 32 vCPUs and 60G memory. 
I also followed [How to speed up Elasticsearch recovery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42923775/how-to-speed-up-elasticsearch-recovery).

When restoring, the memory usage is full. How does elastic search decide how many shards can be restored in parallel?
I was wondering how I can tune my machines' hardware config to make restore faster. If my cluster has more machines, can the restoring speed be improved linearly?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: You can follow the discussion from https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-6-3-0-shard-recovery-is-slow/140940

Comment: My version of ES is 5.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, for ES 6.x there are two  settings that decide how fast is the recovery for primary shards:

- `cluster.routing.allocation.node_initial_primaries_recoveries` Sets the number of primary shards that are recovering in parallel on one node. Defaults is 4. So, for a cluster with N machines, the total number of recovering shards in parallel is N*`node_initial_primaries_recoveries` (See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html#_shard_allocation_settings)
- `indices.recovery.max_bytes_per_sec` Decides how much storage is loaded on recovery per single index. Default is 40mb.  (See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/recovery.html)